# Github user finder api, how to return multiple users per search? JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

Hello I am using github api to create github user finder. my question is how to manipulate on api link to get users which include e.target.value of the searchbar and not only that one that exactly matches.

here is my code

```js
const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState([]);

const handleSearch = async (e) => {
try {
  const URL = `https://api.github.com/users/${e.target.value}? 
  client_id=e25d1dbedde5215999ef&client_secret=ee080580b7c4f19688ccaef6844c3fe88bb811d`;

  Promise.all([fetch(URL).then((res) => res.json())]).then((data) => {
    if (data) {
      setData(data);
    }
  });
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  }
  };

 const setData = (data) => {
  data && setFinalData(data);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Search users endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-users). There is a query parameter (q) that allows you to use multiple search criteria documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-users)

Here's an example using [Octokit](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#search-users), but if you still want to use fetch, the endpoint should be https://api.github.com/search/users

**Note**: I really hope the client secret you are exposing here is for a test application.

| Search GitHub users | [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-71195194) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const userSearch = ''; // Specify the search text here
const usersResponse = await octokit.rest.search.users({
   q: userSearch,
   per_page:100
});

const { total_count, items } = usersResponse.data;
console.log(`Listing ${items.length} users of ${total_count} \n`, items.map(user => user.login));
```